# Submitting Forms form within Jquery UI Tabs using ajax

Tags: jquery

[example page](http://www.csdlogistics.co.uk/example.php)

I have not uploaded the css styles for JQ UI so it looks a bit plain but I am sure you will see what I am intending to do. Most of the tabs will need to load new info from mySQL database so I am assuming that means using AJAX?

Thanks for the help

Comment: okay styles are now added to so you should get the idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

jquery ui tabs is only a nice fancy way to display any webcontent so
you can either submit the form the way you would normally do it, by sending it via post to a page
that handles the form request, 
or you cna do it with ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

whereas data would be $('#form-id').serializeArray() for example

for more infos: [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

**EDIT:**

wrap this around your table:

```
<form method="POST" action="yourtargetfile.php">
     <table>.....</table>
</form>
```

all input fields in the form will be submitted by button press, 
also the submit button must be inside the form

Comment: Hi, thanks for the prompt response. I have tried submitting the form as usual using the usual post method but nothing happens. Where should I place this ajax code in my page? and also could you help me understand the serializeArray() function. How does this work?

Comment: can you post a little bit of your code? might be easier that way

Comment: sorry but I am not sure how I can only see how to add comments? : )

Comment: okay done the edit but just thought, would it shed more light if I put the whole pages worth in? Let me know either way

Comment: you forgot the form tag
<form method="POST"> ..formular... </form> and method="POST" is specified in the form div around the inputs not in the submit button

Comment: okay, so tried that but still not working. I must be doing something wrong. I would really love to be able to handle ajax but just cant get my head around it. If I post my code could you have a look and point me in the right direction?

Comment: well I am only working on the site locally at the minute. Its just over a hundred lines, is that too much to post?

Comment: Hi sharpner, any chance you could take a look at the example page? Thanks

Comment: okay, thanks for all your help. I have decided to go back and learn a bit more about Ajax as I think I need it. Really appreciate all the help.